# Проблема с seekg

Tags: c++

Почему этот код не считывает последний символ?

```
fptr_in.seekg(ios_base::end);  
fptr_in.get(ch);
```

`fptr_in - fstream`. А считывает какой-то 3-ий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уж не потому ли, что ios_base::end равно трем!?!?

Перепишите код так и наступит счастье!

```
 fptr_in.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
 fptr_in.get(ch)
```